# Making a binary search function

Tags: java, sorting, binary-search, insertion-sort

I am working on a homework task where I am supposed to make a function that will do a binary insertion sort, but my function does not seem to work properly.

Here I have tried to combine a binary search function with a insertion sort function (it is specified in the homework task that it needs to be in the form of a function: insertionSort(int[] array, int lo, int hi))

```java
 public static void insertionSort(int[] array, int lo, int hi){
        int mid; 
        int pos; 

        for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {

            int x= array[i]; 

            while (lo < hi) {
                mid = lo + (hi -lo)/2;
                if (x == array[mid]) {
                    pos = mid; 
                }
                if (x > array[mid]) {
                    lo = mid+1; 
                }
                else if (x < array[mid]) {
                    hi = mid-1; 
                }
            }
            pos = lo; 

                for (int j = i; j > pos; j--) {
                array[j] = array[j-1]; 
            }
            array[pos] = x; 
        }
    }
```

If I try to run it with the list {2,5,1,8,3}, the output will be

2 5 1 3 1  (if lo < hi and if lo > hi)

2 5 3 8 5  (if lo==hi)

What I am expecting though, is a sorted list...
Any idea of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The subarray `array[lo .. hi]` must be sorted for a binary search, so initially empty/1 lo == hi == array.ength - 1? I think you need to restart and think about the algorithm. I think here lo or hi should be varying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to give you a possible idea:

```
public static void insertionSort(int[] array) {
    if (array.length <= 1) {
        return;
    }

    // Start with an initially sorted part.
    int loSorted = array.length - 1;
    //int hiSorted = array.length;

    while (loSorted > 0) {

        // Take one from the array
        int x = array[0];

        // Where in the sorted part to insert?
        int insertI = insertPosition(array, loSorted);

        // Insert x at insertI
        ...
        --loSorted;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

whenever I need binary search, my function looks the following way:

```
public static void binarySearch(int arr[], int first, int last, int key){  
           int mid = (first + last)/2;  
           while( first <= last ){  
              if ( arr[mid] < key ){  
                first = mid + 1;     
              }else if ( arr[mid] == key ){  
                System.out.println("Element is found at index: " + mid);  
                break;  
              }else{  
                 last = mid - 1;  
              }  
              mid = (first + last)/2;  
           }  
           if ( first > last ){  
              System.out.println("Element is not found!");  
           }  
         }
```

In your main method the call looks like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
           int arr[] = {10,20,30,40,50};  
            int key = 30;  
            int last=arr.length-1;  
            binarySearch(arr,0,last,key);     
    }
```

I hope I was able to help you!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your input. I changed the function a little bit, and it seems to be working now

` public static void insertionSort(int[] array, int lo, int hi){
        int mid; 
        int pos;

```
    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        int j = i -1;   
        int x = array[i]; 

        while (lo <= hi) {
            mid = lo + (hi -lo)/2;

            if (x == array[mid]) {
                pos = mid; 
                break; 
            }
            if (x > array[mid]) {
                lo = mid+1; 
            }
            else if (x < array[mid]) {
                hi = mid-1; 
            }
        }

        while (j >= 0 && array[j] > x) { 
            array[j + 1] = array[j]; 
            j = j - 1; 
        } 
        array[j + 1] = x;  
    }
}
```

the problem seemed to lay in the last part, where I was trying to move the elements into their right positions. The function is probably not perfect tho, so constructive criticism is welcome :)